# Build IOS with react native: ld: framework not found FIRAnalyticsConnector

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native

I'm integrating firebase into my react native application, basically for authentication and firestore database. Although I followed the installation instructions from the [React Native Firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/), when I tried to build from the xcode, it gives me an error:

```
ld: framework not found FIRAnalyticsConnector clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm using Pods to build the project. Any help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the question.
It's just adding the .framework files into the linked framework.

i.e:

from the xcode, open the Pods folder,

**

> Pods -> Pods -> FirebaseAnalytics -> Frameworks ->
>   FIRAnalyticsConnector.framework

**
[image]

and add that file into the  General -> Linked Frameworks and Libraries.
[image]

Comment: hi, this makes no difference for me... any idea why? Do you know what version of Firebase you are using?